# How to trigger the browser to save file via CGI?

Tags: html, perl, browser, user-interface, cgi

I have the following hidden form:

```
<form id='export_svg_container_single_form'
      action='exportSVG.pl'
      method='post'
      target='_blank'
      style='display:none;'>
  <input type='text'
         id='export_svg_container_single_form_data'
         name='export_svg_data'
         style=';' />
</form>
```

The `export_svg_data` field value gets populated with an SVG document before form submission.

When submitted, this acts on the following simple CGI script, written in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Pretty qw/:standard/;

my $val = param('export_svg_data');
print "Content-Type:image/svg+xml\n";
print "Content-Disposition: inline\n";
print "Content-Description: File to download\n\n";
print $val;
```

When submitted, the hidden form also opens a new tab and displays (in this case) an SVG document. The end user can then save the window to a file.

Instead, on submitting the form, what I would like to do is have the browser automatically open a **Save** or **Save As** dialog box so that the user can pick a filename and save the document, instead of rendering the SVG within the browser window.

How might I do this with JavaScript or the appropriate changes to the CGI script? (I'd like to leave the parent form page untouched, i.e. open a new tab or window, if that is required.) Thanks for your advice.

To clarify again, I am looking for a solution which brings up the **Save** dialog box. I do not want the script to determine the filename and to save it somewhere random, without any user intervention.

Comment: As an aside, instead of printing raw header lines, use `CGI.pm`'s `header`. E.g. `print header(-type => 'image/svg+xml', -attachment => $filename)`. See also http://blog.nu42.com/2012/05/file-download-cgi-script-in-perl.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.svg"`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) instead.

Comment: The problem with this is that the filename is set by the CGI, instead of by the end user. This doesn't bring up the Save file dialog box. Does this help clarify the question?

Comment: How the browser handles it is up to the browser. `inline` means "Try to render it". `attachment` means "Try to save it". Browsers may use the file name as a default and show a Save As dialogue, or they might just save it to a default directory, you can't force one or the other.

Comment: Quentin's right. The script cannot save stuff to the user's computer. Neither the CGI on the server nor the JS on the client's machine can do that. In most browsers there's a setting the user can change on  how saving is done. In the current Firefox this setting is in the left-most tab of the settings dialogue. I only have a German FF at hand. It's called `Extras >> Einstellungen >> Allgemein >> Downloads >> Jedes mal nachfragen, wo eine Datei gespeichert werden soll` there.

Comment: Bummer! I wish I had a way to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

BTW... Can you clarify what is this for? Could be alternative solutions...

Content-Disposition is not going to help universally, what you eventually need is to serve this file from virtual URL, say

/generated-images/generatedname.svg

then you say in your HTML

```
<form ... action="/generated-images/generatedname.svg" ...>
```

and your script similar to these Apache directives (in config or .htaccess), I'm not guaranteeing this to work but I think it's close to truth (you'll also need proper paths and settings to run that CGI by Apache)

```
<Directory /.../generated-images/>
    Action mirror-svg-data /path/somescript.cgi
    AddHandler mirror-svg-data .svg
</Directory>
```

Or you can also rewrite your URLs to script but I'm not sure how internal redirect would work with POST, you may experiment with this:

```
RewriteRule /generated-images/.*\.svg /somepath/script.cgi [L]
```

Good luck!